# Pass data and trigger modal on Angular2 form submit

Tags: angular

I have a modal with a form inside:

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Full Name</label>
                <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fullname" placeholder="Enter full name" name="fullname" ngModel required>
            </div>
             <button [disabled]="!f.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#anotherModal" data-dismiss="modal">
            Confirm
          </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

When Button is clicked, a success modal is triggered:

```
<div id="bookedModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-content" id="bookedModalCorners">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p style="text-align: center">Registration successful!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to send the data collected in the form to parent component via my onSubmit method:

```
  onSubmit(){
    this.details = this.submittedForm.value;
    this.messageEvent.emit(this.details);
  }
```

But due to the first modal/form triggering the second modal, the `onSubmit` method isn't taking effect. If I remove the second modal trigger, the `onSubmit` works just fine. How can I get around this?

Comment: Do you have defined messageEvent as Output?

Comment: Yes I have. Like I said, as soon as I take the second modal trigger from the button, the data is emitted.

Comment: can you share open model method in this question ?

Comment: It's a Bootstrap modal so there's no method that I wrote that triggers it.